Reading a childrens story, what is 背中にまたがって?
「あぁ、もうずいぶん昔にそんな家があったそうじゃ。なんでもそこに住む若者が亀の背中にまたがって海へ行ったきり戻って来なかったという話じゃが・・・」
what is 背中にまたがって?

Does this answer your question:  またがる? See second example sentence.

so its the same as 乗る？亀に乗る

Kind of but not really.  またがる evokes an image of legs straddling whatever you're mounted upon.  There is no sense of coming or going.  Rather, it describes how you are seated upon something.  The English word "straddle" very aptly captures a lot of its connotations but it's usage extends a bit further than the English.

"またがる" here is basically the same as "乗る." 背中 means back. So "背中にまたがって" means "ride on (the turtle's) back."
It is important to note that "またがる" is not always the same as "乗る." 乗る is more common word used for  riding or taking a vehicle, while またがる refers to spreading your legs and gripping what you are riding to stabilize yourself -- the  way to you would ride a horse or a bike.
Here are some examples:

自転車にまたがる (correct; ride on a bike)
自転車に乗る (correct; ride on a bike)
馬にまたがる (correct; ride on a horse)
馬に乗る (correct; ride on a horse)
タクシーにまたがる (this sounds like you are on the top of the taxi, spreading your legs to stabilize yourself)
タクシーに乗る (correct; take a taxi)

People usually imagine riding a turtle's back the same way, whether you use 乗る or またがる.

亀の背中に乗る
亀の背中にまたがる

"亀の背中に乗る" describes any way of being on the turtle's back, whether lying down, standing or sitting. But when you say "亀の背中にまたがる, " it specifically means you are sitting on the turtle's back with your legs spread and gripping its back.
